# Thrift IDL syntax error - accept and return map

Tags: dictionary, thrift, idl

I am writing a thrift server. One of the function is supposed to accept `map` and return a `map` as well.

Following is my thrift file:

```
service base{
    map<string, string>    method_1(1: map<string, double>)
}

service child extends base{
    map<string, string>    method_1(1: map<string, double>),
    void                    method_2(1:string path)
}
```

It says that

```
ERROR: someservice.thrift:4] (last token was ')')
syntax error
```

and I have no idea what is wrong in the syntax.

Comment: dont know what is wrong in this syntax, I typedef'ed both maps, and it works. I am still interested in knowing what is wrong with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **name your arguments**.

```
service base{
  map<string, string>    method_1(1: map<string, double> arg1)
}

service child extends base{
  map<string, string>    method_1(1: map<string, double> arg1),
  void                    method_2(1:string path)
}
```

You already did correctly at `method_2` whose arguments are `(1:string path)`, but then you forgot it at `method_1(1: map<string, double>)` - this is not sufficient.

And by the way, it has absolutely nothing to do with maps.